# writing a 32bit binary value to a file in matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io

I am trying to write a 32bit binary value calculated by using commands to a file in matlab. (I am using matlab online)
However as I try to write to a file, I only find `\n` printed to the file instead of the values. Could anyone help with the issue ?

Below is the code

```
    fid = fopen('hello.txt','w');        
    for i = 1 : 30
    y = (atanh(2^-i))*((2^32)/360)
    n = 32
    m = 0
    d2b = fix(rem(y*pow2(-(n-1):m),2))
    fprintf(fid,'\n',d2b);
    end 
    fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate issue is that your format string provided to `fprintf` doesn't include any information telling it that there is a numeric input that you'd like to print to the file so it will only print the newline, which is exactly what you told it to do.

In your case, the easiest thing is to probably convert the `d2b` to a string of 0's and 1's and then write it using the `'%s'` format specifier.

```
str = num2str(d2b.').';
fprintf(fid, '%s\n', str);
```

Comment: I have tried implementing your suggestion, but the file created is in binary. I was expecting values like `00000000011000111111111110000101` , `00000000001011100111111100011001` which are the ones displayed on the command line. However here the output is different

Comment: @user2559758 Oh you said you wanted binary... It's fixed now.